# Discord bot create unique invite links guild error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I started coding a bot which when prompted would give me a certain number of unique 1 time use invite links to a server in a pre-designated channel inside a server. I am getting error `IndexError: list index out of range`

the code:

```
import discord

token = 'my discord bot token'
client = discord.Client()
number_of_links = input('How many links do you want to create? ') 

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    g = client.guilds[809743502665056306] # getting the error here
    c = g.get_channel(809803698212700190)
    invites = await discord.abc.GuildChannel.invites(c) 

    while len(invites) < int(number_of_links):
        print('CREATING INVITES')
        for i in range(int(number_of_links)): # Create as many links as needed
            i = await discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite(c, max_uses=1, max_age=0, unique=True) # Create the invite link
        break

    print('Finished. Exiting soon...')
    exit()

client.run(token)
```

I tried to also use `g = client.guilds.get(809743502665056306)` but then I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`.

Am I trying to declare the guild incorrectly?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?? Most of this code is completely wrong, where did you get it from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `client.get_guild(809743502665056306)` instead of `client.guilds[809743502665056306]` to solve the error. More details about the get_guild function [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild).

The `on_ready` function gets called many times while the bot is running, so you may want to make a [command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) instead of using an event.